# Ajax error: firers off alert when data is returned on GET MVC 4

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working with a MVC project that has an Index view with link buttons that link to multiple controllers. When a user clicks on the a link and there's no data returned I need to display an alert box to the user.

I have updated my code after a few more days of research on Ajax with MVC 4, and found a partial solution to the original problem, which was to scrap the jQuery code below I commented out, and simply add a function to alert the user if no data was returned. I'm using in my view the the @Ajax.ActionLink method below, which does return the correct data if available.

One problem I can't seem to figure out is why the onFailure jQuery function does not fire off when there is no data returned from the data base.

This is an HTML example for one of the buttons in my MVC view:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("View Case test", "Index", "CaseInfo", 
                    new RouteValueDictionary{{"id", Model.AttorneyID }}, 
                    new AjaxOptions{ HttpMethod = "Post",  
                                     UpdateTargetId = "ui-widget-content", 
                                     OnFailure = "casefailure",
                                     InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace })
```

I replaced the original script block that I commented out with a simple function called casefailures that will popup an alert box. This alert whoever never fires off when no data is returned for the DB.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () { 
    function casefailure() {
        alert("No case files returned for this user.");
    }
}
```

This was the old script

```
//$('#caseInfoBtn').click(function () {
//    var attorneyId = $(this).data('AttorneyID');

//    $.ajax({
//        cache: false,
//        async: true,
//        type: 'POST',
//        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
//        url: '/JsonIndex/CaseInfo/' + attorneyId,
//        success: function (retData) {
//            $('.ui-widget-content').html(retData);
//        },
//        error: function () {
//            alert('There where no Court Cases returned for this Attorney.');
//        }
//    });
//});
```

This is the controller for the ActionLink above"

```
public ActionResult Index(int id)
    {
        var caseList = unitOfWork.CaseInfoRepository.Get()
                                 .Where(c => c.AttorneyId == id)
                                 .OrderBy(o => o.CaseAnsweringParty);

        if (caseList.Any() && WebSecurity.IsConfirmed(GetLoggedInUser))
        { 
            IEnumerable<CaseInfoIndexViewModel> vModel = 
                Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<CaseInfo>, IList<CaseInfoIndexViewModel>>(caseList);

            if (vModel != null)
            {
                return View(vModel);
            }
        }
        //No Cases returned so return to Attorney Index
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Attorney");

    }
```

Thanks to all the replies so far it was appreciated!

Comment: change 'asynch:true' to 'async:true' in ajax function and 'sucess:function' to 'success:function'try

Comment: asynch is already set to true...

Comment: not asynch its async spelling mistake..!

Comment: Ok I see my spelling errors, and have edited the original post. I am still getting the same alert every time I click the View Case button.

Comment: Put semicolon in end of your ajax function ;

Comment: Added the semicolon to to the end of the ajax function but I still have the same issue.

Comment: see i am not good in mvc but your ajax syntax is correct only.. and  be sure the given link in your url is correct...check the flow of your program

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 $('#caseInfoBtn').click(function () {
        var attorneyId = $(this).data('AttorneyID');

        $.ajax({
            cache:false,
            async:true,
            type:'GET',
            url:'/Index/CaseInfo/attorneyId',
            data:{ 'id': attorneyId },
            success:function (retData) {
                $('.ui-widget-content').html(retData);
            },
            error:function () {
                alert('There where no Court Cases returned for this Attorney.');
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: I coped and pasted your example into my script file and still have the same alert popup. I tried different browsers with mix results. IE will display the alert on every click, Chrome does not display the alert at all, and FireFox briefly displays the alert and then shows the returned data for the Court Cases

Answer (score 0):

The error event could be firing for many different reasons (eg; a CORS error, an error at the server, etc..).  An easy way to investigate it further is to hit F12 in Chrome and use the network tab while making the ajax call.  From there, you should be able to see the response from the server, which should cast more light on the problem.

Comment: In Chromes editor Network tab all the required scripts and and page loads return a 200 Ok status after clicking on the action link.

Comment: You might want to check the data type that is being returned.  For example, if the ajax call is expecting JSON data, but the data cannot be parsed as JSON, the error event will fire even though the server response is a 200.

Comment: First thanks for the help Matt. I've change my original post to reflect the current issue after making some changes. My problem now is not the random alert popup but no alert at all when there is no data returned from the DB. The Ajax Action Link in the view has a onFailure call to casefailure that's a function in my script file, which only has an alert message that never fires off. If data is returned from the DB the data displays just fine in the view.